# ¿como evitar que mi modal de bootstrap no se cierre con el teclado y solo con el bonton aceptar del mismo modal?

Tags: c#, bootstrap, .net, asp

Hola he creado un modal de boostrap y le he quitado el ×

y por supuesto no tiene un boton cancelar, solo uno aceptar que me direcciona a otra pagina.
Bueno, lo que necesito esque mi modal no se cierre con la tecla ESC ni dando click a otra parte de la pantalla (ya que tambien se cierra), sola y unicamente que se quede ahi y no se cierre, una vez que el usuario haga click en abrir modal, ya no lo pueda quitar.
Existe alguna manera?
Gracias
Saludos

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion de webform asp .net con c#

Comment: pobre de la persona a la cual se le cuelgue el mouse.. o tenga otro problema y se le cuelgue algo de su pc.. no seria mejor, trabajar todos esos caminos en lugar de bloquearle el uso de su pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasandole opciones a la modal por medio de jQuery `$('#myModal').modal(options)` options es un objeto de opciones y tiene un atributo `backdrop` el cual se le puede especificar que sea estatico, es decir que la ventana no se cierre al hacer click por fuera de esta:

```
$('#myModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static'
  });
```

Para más información pude ver la documentación de boostrap: [Opciones de modal boostrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#options)

Comment: Hola gracias, lo he probado pero no me funciona.... :c

Comment: lo he resuleto con esto: data-backdrop="false"